# Retrieve "n-1" and "n+1" element of each position in a for loop

Tags: java, algorithm, iterator, jgrapht, digraphs

I have a digraph (created using the jgrapht library) which takes as vertices Point objects. I add vertices and edges as a flood fill algorithm goes through a given matrix. I created it using this code:

```
public static DirectedGraph<Point, DefaultEdge> directedGraph = new DefaultDirectedGraph<Point, DefaultEdge>(DefaultEdge.class);

    public static class FloodFill {


  public static void resolution(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Found loop: "+checkIfPositionIsInLoop(matrix, 2, 7, 3));


    //result
    System.out.println("-------------------"); 

    for (int i=0; i<matrix.length; i++) {
      for (int j=0; j<matrix[i].length; j++) {
        System.out.print(matrix[i][j] + " ");
      }
      System.out.print("\n");
    }
    System.out.print("\n");
  }

  private static Direction direction;

  public static boolean checkIfPositionIsInLoop(int[][] matrix, int x, int y, int fillValue) {
    int targetX = x;
    int targetY = y;

    return fillReachesTargetPosition(matrix, x, y, targetX, targetY, fillValue, Direction.LEFT );
  }

  private static boolean fillReachesTargetPosition(int[][] matrix, int x, int y, int targetX, int targetY, int fillValue, Direction forbiddenDirection) {

    if (x>=matrix.length)
      return false;
    if (y>=matrix[x].length)
      return false;

    int originValue=matrix[x][y];
    matrix[x][y]=fillValue;

    int xToFillNext;
    int yToFillNext;

    boolean fillingReachedTargetPosition = false;

    // Up
    xToFillNext = x-1;
    yToFillNext = y;
    if (xToFillNext==targetX && yToFillNext==targetY && !forbiddenDirection.equals(Direction.UP)) {
      Point myPoint = new Point(x, y);
      Point myNextPoint = new Point(xToFillNext, yToFillNext);
      directedGraph.addVertex(myPoint);
      directedGraph.addVertex(myNextPoint);
      directedGraph.addEdge(myPoint, myNextPoint);
      //outEdgesMap.put(myPoint,outEdgesMap.get(myPoint)+1);
      return true;
    } else if (xToFillNext>=0 && originValue==matrix[xToFillNext][yToFillNext] && !forbiddenDirection.equals(Direction.UP)) {  
      Point myPoint = new Point(x, y);
      Point myNextPoint = new Point(xToFillNext, yToFillNext);
      directedGraph.addVertex(myPoint);
      directedGraph.addVertex(myNextPoint);
      directedGraph.addEdge(myPoint, myNextPoint); 
      //outEdgesMap.put(myPoint, outEdgesMap.get(myPoint)+1);  
      fillingReachedTargetPosition = 
        fillReachesTargetPosition(matrix, xToFillNext, yToFillNext, targetX, targetY, fillValue, Direction.DOWN );
      if (fillingReachedTargetPosition) {
        return true;
      }
    }

    // Right
    xToFillNext = x;
    yToFillNext = y+1;
    if (xToFillNext==targetX  && yToFillNext==targetY && !forbiddenDirection.equals(Direction.RIGHT)) {
      Point myPoint = new Point(x, y);
      Point myNextPoint = new Point(xToFillNext, yToFillNext);
      directedGraph.addVertex(myPoint);
      directedGraph.addVertex(myNextPoint);
      directedGraph.addEdge(myPoint, myNextPoint);
      //outEdgesMap.put(myPoint, outEdgesMap.get(myPoint)+1);
      return true;
    } else if (yToFillNext<matrix[xToFillNext].length && originValue==matrix[xToFillNext][yToFillNext] && !forbiddenDirection.equals(Direction.RIGHT)) {
      Point myPoint = new Point(x, y);
      Point myNextPoint = new Point(xToFillNext, yToFillNext);
      directedGraph.addVertex(myPoint);
      directedGraph.addVertex(myNextPoint);
      directedGraph.addEdge(myPoint, myNextPoint);
      //outEdgesMap.put(myPoint, outEdgesMap.get(myPoint)+1);
      fillingReachedTargetPosition = 
        fillReachesTargetPosition(matrix, xToFillNext, yToFillNext, targetX, targetY, fillValue, Direction.LEFT );
      if (fillingReachedTargetPosition) {
        return true;
      }
    }

    // Down
    xToFillNext = x+1;
    yToFillNext = y;
    if (xToFillNext==targetX && yToFillNext==targetY && !forbiddenDirection.equals(Direction.DOWN)) {
      Point myPoint = new Point(x, y);
      Point myNextPoint = new Point(xToFillNext, yToFillNext);
      directedGraph.addVertex(myPoint);
      directedGraph.addVertex(myNextPoint);
      directedGraph.addEdge(myPoint, myNextPoint);
      //outEdgesMap.put(myPoint, outEdgesMap.get(myPoint)+1);
      return true;
    } else if (xToFillNext<matrix.length  && originValue==matrix[xToFillNext][yToFillNext] && !forbiddenDirection.equals(Direction.DOWN)) {
      Point myPoint = new Point(x, y);
      Point myNextPoint = new Point(xToFillNext, yToFillNext);
      directedGraph.addVertex(myPoint);
      directedGraph.addVertex(myNextPoint);
      directedGraph.addEdge(myPoint, myNextPoint);
      //outEdgesMap.put(myPoint, outEdgesMap.get(myPoint)+1);
      fillingReachedTargetPosition = 
        fillReachesTargetPosition(matrix, xToFillNext, yToFillNext, targetX, targetY, fillValue, Direction.UP );  
      if (fillingReachedTargetPosition) {
        return true;
      }
    }

    // Left
    xToFillNext = x;
    yToFillNext = y-1;
    if (xToFillNext==targetX && yToFillNext==targetY && forbiddenDirection.equals(Direction.RIGHT)) {
      Point myPoint = new Point(x, y);
      Point myNextPoint = new Point(xToFillNext, yToFillNext);
      directedGraph.addVertex(myPoint);
      directedGraph.addVertex(myNextPoint);
      directedGraph.addEdge(myPoint, myNextPoint);
      //outEdgesMap.put(myPoint, outEdgesMap.get(myPoint)+1);
      return true;
    } else if (yToFillNext>=0 && originValue==matrix[xToFillNext][yToFillNext] && !forbiddenDirection.equals(Direction.LEFT)) {

      Point myPoint = new Point(x, y);
      Point myNextPoint = new Point(xToFillNext, yToFillNext);
      directedGraph.addVertex(myPoint);
      directedGraph.addVertex(myNextPoint);
      directedGraph.addEdge(myPoint, myNextPoint);
      //outEdgesMap.put(myPoint, outEdgesMap.get(myPoint)+1);
      fillingReachedTargetPosition = 
        fillReachesTargetPosition(matrix, xToFillNext, yToFillNext, targetX, targetY, fillValue, Direction.RIGHT );
      if (fillingReachedTargetPosition) {
        return true;
      }
    }

    return false;
  }
}

public static class Point {

  public int x;
  public int y;

  public  Point(int x, int y) 
  {

    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
  }
  @Override
    public String toString() {
    return ("[x="+x+" y="+y+"]");
  }

  @Override
    public int hashCode() {
    int hash = 7;
    hash = 71 * hash + this.x;
    hash = 71 * hash + this.y;
    return hash;
   }



  @Override
    public boolean equals(Object other) 
  {
    if (this == other)
      return true;

    if (!(other instanceof Point))
      return false;

    Point otherPoint = (Point) other;
    return otherPoint.x == x && otherPoint.y == y;
  }
}
```

Now, I display the number of outwards vertices of each vertex using:

```
for(Point myPoint : directedGraph.vertexSet()){
   int degree = directedGraph.outDegreeOf(myPoint);
   }
```

I want to add a if statement having as condition the number of outwards vertices. For example:

```
for(Point myPoint : directedGraph.vertexSet()){
       int degree = directedGraph.outDegreeOf(myPoint);
if (degree >= 2 // This is the degree of the element number n){
// use n-1,n+1, n+2 etc element
}
```

My question is how can I access the n-1,n+1, n+2 (etc) elements of an element ? 
Is it the right case to use an iterator ?

Comment: What is the return type of `vertexSet()` method? Is it `Set<Point>`?

Comment: it returns the Point objects which were added as vertices. For example, it can return: [[x=2 y=7] [x=4 y=8] [x=1 y=9]] , these being the three vertices of the graph (3 Point objects)

Comment: I'm asking about the return type. How it's declared in the java code? `public Set<Point> vertexSet() {...}`? Or something else?

Comment: I didn't have to declare it since it's from the jgrapht library, which says: Set<V> vertexSet()

Comment: But since I use Point objects as vertices yes it is supposed to be:
'Set<Point> vertexSet()'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the methods: `predecessorListOf()` and `successorListOf()` which can more or less solve my problem since I don't have a better option.